# Oracle SQL order by clause for varchar when using ibatis.xml mapping

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, ibatis

I am trying to get a varchar50 colunn to sort correctly using an Order By clause in the orderspec

sample data:

```
test123
Test45
47589 Joe
34 Alex
23478 amy
Brian 5
brian 4789
```

It really can be any combination of numbers and characters up to 50.

Basically I need it to sort:
numbers only (in order regardless of length, ie 1, 2, 3,10 rather than 1, 10, 2, 3
Then it needs to sort alphabetically, regardless of case, based on the first word in the string.

The column is a varchar50 on an oracle DB.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<sql id="order-by-clause">
  <isPropertyAvailable property="OrderSpec">
    <isNotNull property="OrderSpec">
      ORDER BY
       <isEqual property="OrderSpec.Property" compareValue="javascriptName">
        mcn.my_column_name
       </isEqual>
      $OrderSpec.Direction$
    </isNotNull>
  </isPropertyAvailable>
</sql>
```

As you can see we are passing in the sort direction (ASC/DESC) from the ui.

Currently the default sorting on the colummn is not producing the desired results, and I need to be able to tweak it accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the XML and IBATIS thing. But if you can pass any `ORDER BY` using the `XML` to `ORACLE` you need to convert the strings numeric part to numeric and sort it and then sort the alphanumeric. It is some tricky regular expressions that need to be used.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a581f/35) about this. Whole SQL SELECT would look like this

```
select mcn.my_column_name,  lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'^[0-9]*')),10,'0')
        || lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*$')),10,'0')
        || regexp_replace(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*') as sortcrit
from tst
order by  lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'^[0-9]*')),10,'0')
        || lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*$')),10,'0')
        || regexp_replace(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*')
```

As I said before I am not sure how the tool you work with ticks but I guess your XML must look like this:

```
<sql id="order-by-clause">
  <isPropertyAvailable property="OrderSpec">
    <isNotNull property="OrderSpec">
      ORDER BY
       <isEqual property="OrderSpec.Property" compareValue="javascriptName">
        lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'^[0-9]*')),10,'0')
    || lpad(to_number(regexp_substr(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*$')),10,'0')
    || regexp_replace(mcn.my_column_name,'[0-9]*') 
       </isEqual>
      $OrderSpec.Direction$
    </isNotNull>
  </isPropertyAvailable>
</sql>
```

Hope it works.